# Create a slanted edge to a div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Im trying to create a slanted div, and everywhere I have looked I have just found how to do it using a border of some sorts, which will not work because the div will be places over the top of an image.

So the code at the moment is as follows using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="banner.jpg">
        <h3 class="headline-badge">slanted div text</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant CSS:

```
.thumbnail img.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.headline-badge {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

So I want to create a slant towards the top right. I tried using a border with little or no success, and whenever I tried to make the border transparent it wouldn't display the border.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to create this using CSS? I believe it should also be responsive which is a major issue as the slant cannot just be a fixed height/width.

The slant should be around 45 degrees, and only on the right hand side of the div. The text shouldn't be effected by the slant.

The effect should be similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yLu1sxmj/

Thanks for posting this fiddle, but I need to actually add text to the div, and your solution makes it difficult to do this as the comments in reply suggest. The slant would also need to be slanting upwards, not downwards, and I struggled to do this without effecting the left of the div. With your example I couldn't figure out how to add text on top of the div though I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you have an example of what it should look like?

Comment: What kind of slant? How slanted? What's your desired degree of slantiness? Do you mean something like [this kind of slant](http://jsfiddle.net/9j02jxc7/), or perhaps a different type of slant? A slant to the left? A slant to the right? A 80degree slant would give you a fright! Perhaps a slant on only the left edge, or maybe a wiggly slant to make it look like a hedge?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, just a standard 45 degree slant towards the top right. @MLeFevre you are correct, but I only want the right hand side to be slanted, and no slanted text. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Web-tiki's answer in the linked question is what you're looking for (responsive)

Comment: His answer was not completely correct, and as people pointed out in his thread its difficult to add any text to his solution. Anyway, I don't know how to un-duplicate this question.

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks for your help, but I think the question will have slipped down the pecking order now :P

Comment: @web-tiki I need to put the text over the top of the block of colour. And I would also need to angle the slant the other way, slanting upwards. I tried doing this but couldn't get it to work at all

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use a skewed pseudo element to make the slanted solid background of your element. This way, the text won't be affected by the transform property.

The transform origin property allows the pseudo element to be skewed from the right bottom corner and the overflowwing parts are hidden with `overflow:hidden;`.

The pseudo element is stacked behind the content of the div with a negative `z-index`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  background: url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>slanted div text</div>
<div>
  slanted div text<br/> on several lines<br/> an other line
</div>
<div>wider slanted div text with more text inside</div>
```

Comment: When I add `position: absolute` I lose the black background, do you know why? As you can see from my code, this positioning is used to place the text on the top left of the image on top of it, as the HTML code is actually an `img` and `div` (I changed the `h3` to a `div`)

Comment: @germainelol please share the code that reproduces your issue so I can see how to fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/31myb1vp/1/ here is a jsfiddle, sorry I included all of bootstrap it would take too long to pick out the parts I wanted, but at the top is the relevant CSS to the HTML

Comment: @germainelol the issue is that the slanted element was hidding behind the image. I solved it using `z-index:1;` on `.headline-badge` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/31myb1vp/3/

Comment: excellent thank you, I didn't think to simply use the `z-index`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On a project recently, I used SkewY and SkewX, this essentially made it so that I did not need to use overflow hidden which was a great relief.

Answer (score 18):

This can be achieved easily using CSS `clip-path` (and `-webkit-clip-path`)

[Example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXBbLO)

I also found [this handy tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to generate the CSS code with minimum fuss.

Comment: I upvoted for mentioning Clippy tool. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to add a slant for a banner or a simple click area. The suggestion I would give comes from how the major websites like amazon and google do it. It is as follows:

Create a vector image that has the slant that you want where it covers the proportion of the div that you want. Then when you add it as an overlay you can set it as position:absolute with a z-index greater than anything in the div.

This will greatly reduce the processing and the cached image will load as quickly as css. This will also prevent cross browser issues.

I hope this helps.

PS: Vector images re size nicely so you don't have to worry about pixelation and anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
**background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(113, 182, 46, .6) 78%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%);**
```

Comment: Without any explanation as to why you're recommending this particular solution or how it works exactly, it's not clear to anyone whether or not this solution will work for them. Remember, you're not just answer for the OP, but you're also answering for everyone who finds your answer when looking for a solution a similar problem they might be having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it doesn't work when you have an image as the background of the parent element. I used an inline svg background instead.

Html

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="slanted">
         I have a slanted edge
     </div>
   </div>
```

Css

```
    .parent {
              background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/350');
              background-size: cover;
              background-position: center center;
              padding: 100px;
     }

    .slanted {
                color: white;
                background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 200 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  preserveAspectRatio='none'><polygon points='0,300 0,0 150,0 300,300' width='100%' height='100%' style='fill:blue;'/></svg>");
                background-size:contain;
                width: 30%;
                font-size: 2em;
                padding: 4px 40px;
   }
```

Note: You may have to play around with the svg and height and width a little. The accepted answer should work for most cases. It didn't work for me because I had a parent element that had an image background.

Here are some resources on the svg tag:

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp