# Skew a Partial Div but not its content.

Tags: html, css

I was trying to skew a div but not its content regardless of whether it is image or text which should be vertical.

I have gone through many of the question related to my error on stack like
[Create a slanted edge to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410329/create-a-slanted-edge-to-a-div),
[How to skew element but keep text normal (unskewed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947565/how-to-skew-element-but-keep-text-normal-unskewed)

In my aspect, nothing seems to help.

I have placed the image on to the left and text on to the right both of them should be skewed. but when I flip them like placing an image on to the right and (vice versa), it should justify itself.

Here is an inspirational image.

[image: Inspiration]

and here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/qze2tmfc/) I've worked for it.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="partial-section">
    <div class="section-inner">
      <div id="parallelogram">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="partial-section">
    <h1> This is some heading on the right partial section.</h1>
    <p>Some random text that should be appeared on the right side of the partial section. This should be below the heading the partial section has and should fill the empty space that it has.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
  height: 450px;
}

.partial-section {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.partial-section h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.partial-section p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.section-inner {
  height: inherit;
}

#parallelogram {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/601/301);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skew(40deg);
}
```

It would be a great pleasure if someone could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) as well.

Comment: could you spare some of your time to help me out?

Comment: Ok. You should have a common parent with `overflow hidden`. On left column there will be image without any transformation and on right column there will be text without any background and transformation. Use a pseudo element on right column with full height and background and apply skew transformation to this pseudo element. Have you got the point?

Comment: Just in case if anyone want jsFiddle, here is link: https://jsfiddle.net/83pdLum5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this question (about slanted edges) and line of thinking (to use skew) come up frequently. Skew is super cool, and useful for some effects, but IMO this isn't one of those times.

I'd recommend adding an `:after` pseudo element and creating a CSS triangle to create the effect you want. This will eliminate the need to undo the skew for the content.

To keep the image and content elements at equal width I've used a width of `calc(50% +/- Xpx)` but this is just nitpicky stuff. If you don't mind one side being a little larger/smaller you can set the width of both to a fixed `50%`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
  height: 450px;
}

.partial-section {
  width: calc(50% - 25px);
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.partial-section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.partial-section p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.partial--padded {
  padding: 20px;
}

.section-inner {
  height: inherit;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/601/301);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.slanted {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% + 25px);
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.slanted:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
 border-bottom: 450px solid red;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slanted">
      <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partial-section partial--padded">
    <h1> This is some heading on the right partial section.</h1>
    <p>Some random text that should be appeared on the right side of the partial section. This should be below the heading the partial section has and should fill the empty space that it has.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you **really** want to use a `skew` to get some experience with it, we can still go the `:after` pseudo element route, create a red rectangle, and skew it to make a slanted edge. This again eliminates the need to undo a skew on the inner content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
  height: 450px;
}

.partial-section {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.partial-section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.partial-section p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.partial--padded {
  padding: 20px;
}

.section-inner {
  height: inherit;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/601/301);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.slanted {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: inherit;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slanted:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-5deg);
  transform: skew(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slanted">
      <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partial-section partial--padded">
    <h1> This is some heading on the right partial section.</h1>
    <p>Some random text that should be appeared on the right side of the partial section. This should be below the heading the partial section has and should fill the empty space that it has.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the question, what if I flip the content like the image on the right and text on to the left?

Comment: Easy, just reposition the `:after` pseudo element to the right-side, and flip the triangle/skew the other direction.