# How to create an one side only slanting ribbon ? using CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I need your help to create something like this that is also reponsive in mobile. the text inside can vary in length.
[image]
So far,
able to create the following code below,
[image]

Whats a good approach for such thing?

CSS below

```
<style>
  .box {
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid green; 
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    margin: 5px;
    background:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon points="16,17 16,-2 0,-1" fill="yellow" stroke="green" /></svg>') bottom right/30px 100%,  /* Adjusted background position here */
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15 15" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon points="16,16 16,-2 0,16" fill="white" stroke="white" /></svg>') bottom right/0px 0%,
      yellow content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
</style>
```

HTML Below

```
<div class="box">Reinventing Growth Opportunities</div>
```

Although i am able to create something like this
[image]

using psuedo class but the border is not applying

[image]

```
<h4 class="ribbon">Reinventing Growth Opportunities</h4>
```

```
.ribbon {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4c6fff;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    /* border: 3px solid black; */
}

.ribbon::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -1em;
    border-top: 2.5em solid #4c6fff;
    border-right: 1em solid transparent;
    bottom: 0em;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: I hope this page will fulfil your requirement:
[Create a slanted edge to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410329/create-a-slanted-edge-to-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skew transformation on pseudo element can do this:

```css
.ribbon {
  --b: 2px; /* border width */
  --c: red; /* border color */
  
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ribbon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0 0 0 calc(-1*var(--b));
  background: lightblue; /* background color */
  border: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: skewX(-20deg); /* control the slant */
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">Some text here</div>
```